# UICollectionView: cellForItemAt isn't called properly

Tags: uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a UICOllectionView with a stack of subviews, with the possibility to add and delete different subviews.
The problem is that cellForItemAt is not called properly. E.g. numberOfItemsInSection is set to 4 so I would expect 4 subviews. However, cellForItemAt is not called for all items, only for visible, and it is being called only when I scroll through this UICollectionView. Is there any way to call it for all items at once ?
Another problem is that after scrolling through UICollectionView to the end it adds additional subview, which corresponds to one of the previous subviews.
[image]

[image]

[image]
So it is not clear, why cellForItemAt is called as soon as all items were shown. And how it choses indexPath.row for this additional item.
The last strange thing is that cellForItemAt is being called once again as I scroll back , so it adds subviews to the cells which already have some subviews so that they are stacked one above another:
[image]
It seems, that the way UIcollection works is completely different from principles in UITableView

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView isn't that different really to UITableView really.
'cellForItemAt' is called each time a cell is about to become visible so on first load it will only be called for your visible cells, which is the behaviour your seeing. As you scroll through it will be called for each cell as they appear. This makes it more memory efficient as cells are reused and only created when needed.

I'm not sure you can force it to load all cells initially without a bit of hacky code to either scroll the collection view yourself or programatically call the code you want yourself. Without understanding your implementation better this probably isn't what you want.

The additional cellForItem call when you scroll to the end is probably due to the collection view 'bouncing' on the last cell and reloading a previous one due to the animation. Also 'indexPath.row' should probably be replaced with 'indexPath.item' for collection views but this shouldn't really affect your implementation.

Comment: I removed both bounce on scroll and bounce on zoom, but the effect , when in one place there are two different indexpath.item (one label above another) is still present. And if the cellForItemAt each time creates a new cell, why there is such pileup of labels? I thought, that in this case one should expect a new cell each time it becomes visible .